# yii2 - Display multiple tables in same page using multi column layout

Tags: yii2

How I can display separated and independent GridView tables (in my case from `kartik`) in each page column, like sort of Dashboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try in this way

For view

```
 //  Firts Column 

 <div class= 'col-md-6'>
    <?php 
       echo  GridView::widget([
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider1,
            'filterModel' => $searchModel1,
            'columns' => [
                ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
                        .....
            ],
        ]); 
    ?>

  </div>
  // separator column
  <div class='col-md-1'></div>

  // Second column
  <div class='col-md-5'>

    <?php
        echo GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider2,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel2,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
                         .....
        ], 
        ]); 
      ?>
  </div>
```

for controller

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    // Migration already done
    $searchModel1 = new YuorFirtsModelSearch();
    $dataProvider1 = $searchModel1->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    $searchModel2 = new YuorSecodnModelSearch();
    $dataProvider2 = $searchModel2->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

     // Render All
    return $this->render('indexNew', [
        'searchModel1' => $searchModel1,
        'dataProvider1' => $dataProvider1,
        'searchModel2' => $serachModel2,
        'dataProvider2' => $dataProvider2,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but if I need to view data from different models on each column, what about che controller logic?

Comment: ok... but if I need to output different models (modelA and modelB) attributes on the same view, and every model has its own controller (controllerA and controllerB), which controller would pick both modelA and modelB data for rendering in the view? A new one?

Comment: This is only an application design question.
I think in the controller that you deem fit for purpose. In some case a  new one is the correct choice in others there is a prevalent controller who lead this part of application. Is a yuor application choice